# Mysql suma y agrupacion con 2 tablas

Tags: mysql, select, sql, tablas

Tengo un problema con una consulta de mysql. Dia a dia voy adentrándome mas pero estoy muy atorado ya que no se por donde encarar esta consulta

Tengo 2 tablas, con codigos y valores. En la tabla A los codigos nunca se repiten, mientras que en la B puede haber varias con el mismo codigo (siempre estos existen en la A, pero los de la A pueden no existir en la B). Cada uno tiene un valor. En la A el valor_total es el valor total de A mas los que tienen el mismo codigo de la B. A veces coinciden, a veces no. Yo quiero hacer una consulta que me de como resultado los que no coinciden!

Ejemplo: Tabla A

```
id - codigo - valor - valor_total
0  - 100    - 25    -   25
1  - 102    - 10    -   11
2  - 105    - 35    -   70
3  - 110    - 12    -   35
4  - 150    - 105   -   105
5  - 151    - 106   -   300
```

Tabla B

```
id  -  codigo  -  valor
0   -  105     -  10
1   -  105     -  20
2   -  105     -  11
3   -  110     -  20
4   -  110     -  3
5   -  151     -  28
6   -  151     -  4
7   -  151     -  11
```

El resultado me deberia dar los que no coinciden el valor_total de A con la suma del valor de A mas los que tengan su mismo codigo de B
Serian: 102 - 105 - 151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente a mí se sobra el 102, pues no aparece en B. En ese caso, la consulta sería:

```
SELECT *,valor+valor_total_b valor_total_a FROM (
  SELECT codigo,SUM(valor) valor_total_b
    FROM tabla_b GROUP BY 1
  ) c1 JOIN tabla_a USING(codigo)
  WHERE valor+valor_total_b!=valor_total;
```

Se puede comprobar a partir del dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla_a(
  id int,
  codigo int,
  valor int,
  valor_total int,
  UNIQUE(id),
  UNIQUE(codigo)
  );
INSERT INTO tabla_a (id, codigo, valor, valor_total) VALUES 
  (0  , 100    , 25    ,   25),
  (1  , 102    , 10    ,   11),
  (2  , 105    , 35    ,   70),
  (3  , 110    , 12    ,   35),
  (4  , 150    , 105   ,   105),
  (5  , 151    , 106   ,   300);
CREATE TABLE tabla_b(
  id int,
  codigo int,
  valor int,
  FOREIGN KEY(codigo) REFERENCES tabla_a(codigo)
  );
INSERT INTO tabla_b (id, codigo, valor) VALUES
  (0   ,  105     ,  10),
  (1   ,  105     ,  20),
  (2   ,  105     ,  11),
  (3   ,  110     ,  20),
  (4   ,  110     ,  3),
  (5   ,  151     ,  28),
  (6   ,  151     ,  4),
  (7   ,  151     ,  11);
```

Y, para el caso de que quieras incluir al 102 y otros tantos:

```
SELECT *,valor+valor_total_b valor_total_a FROM (
  SELECT codigo,SUM(valor) valor_total_b
    FROM tabla_b GROUP BY 1
  ) c1 RIGHT JOIN tabla_a USING(codigo)
  WHERE valor+valor_total_b!=valor_total
    OR valor_total_b IS NULL;
```

Por favor, confírmame si es el resultado que esperabas y qué partes de la consulta no entiendes para poder explicarla un poquito.

Comment: El 102 es un ejemplo de que puede haber una diferencia en la tabla A directamente sin tener datos en la B. Puede ser que le faltan comas? el valor_total_b seria tabla_b.valor ? Cuando intento ponerle los valores según la tabla que creaste me da algunos errores que deben ser por estas diferencias, voy a ver si le encuentro la forma

Comment: Esta muy bien, estaba cometiendo yo un error! En el caso del 102 da null-null cuando deberia marcarlo como diferencia... voy a intentar comprender tu solución a ver si puedo hacer que solo me de como resultado los 3 codigos solamente! Mil gracias

Comment: Ten en cuenta que cualquier operación por NULL da NULL. Es decir NULL+1=NULL, por ejemplo. Puedes utilizar `IFNULL(campo,0)` para convertirlo en un cero. Para que sólo te dé los códigos, sustituye el * por codigo y elimina el resto hasta el FROM.

Comment: Si tienes cualquier dificultad, modifica la pregunta con el resultado que esperas para ese dataset y yo haré lo propio con la respuesta. No te olvides de incorporar lo que hayas intentado como solución para poder ayudarte en lo que sea que no sepas cómo hacer.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! Ahi hice una modificacion para que solo tome los 3 codigos diferentes: SELECT codigo FROM ( SELECT codigo,SUM(valor) valor_total_b FROM tabla_b GROUP BY 1 ) c1 RIGHT JOIN tabla_a USING(codigo) WHERE valor+valor_total_b!=valor_total OR (valor_total_b IS NULL and valor_total_b IS NULL and valor_total!=valor)

Comment: Genial, veo que ya lo tienes controlado... Me alegra haberte ayudado